# Trying to produce a function that separates a data frame, based on values within a column, and then produces new data frames from that separated data

Tags: r

I am trying to produce a function in R that allows me to produce a new series of data frames based on values contained with a specified column in another dataframe. I have been using the palmer penguins package to try and sort this out. Essentially I am trying to create a function that does this:

```
penguins%>%
  group_by(species)%>%
  group_split(species)
```

Allowing me to have all the original values separated by a value of interest. However, when I try to create a function I end up with an error:

```
variable_isolation <- function(x){
  group_by(df[{{x}}])%>%
  group_split(df[{{x}}])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `df[{{x}}]` use only `{{x}}` and pass the dataframe and variable to the function.

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(dplyr)

variable_isolation <- function(data, x){
  data %>% group_split({{x}})
}

penguins %>% variable_isolation(species)
#Or
#variable_isolation(penguins, species)
```